# koa.js returning 404 "Not Found" after signup, instead of the token from ctx.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, supertest, koa2

I'm failing to return my `token` to actually be retrieved from my middlewares using xhr agents *say `supertest` and `postman`.* after I signup my user.

I'm trying to get the jwt from body so i can make authenticated requests, but for some reason i keep on getting "Not Found".

Please take a look at my code..

**signup route**

```js
router.post('/signup', signUp);
```

What important about `/signup` route, is if I add a middleware after `signUp` I can access the `ctx.response.body` passed from `signUp` middleware but I can't publish it anyware. *Or i don't know how*.

and **the signUp middleware**

```js
const signUp = async (ctx, next) => {
    
    const bodyInfo = await ctx.request.body;

    if(!bodyInfo.username || !bodyInfo.password) {
        ctx.status = 402;
        ctx.body = "Error, username and password must be provided!";
    }

    const userInst = new User(bodyInfo);

    userInst.save(async(err, user) => {
        
        if(err) { return next(err); }

        const token = tokenForUser(user);

        ctx.body = token;

        return next();
    });
};

export { signUp, signIn };
```

I should mention that this saved the data fine and when I check in the database the data is there, `console.logs` of `ctx.response.body` in a  next middleware to `signUp` shows the generated token too.

I **test /signup** with this code:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    a_user = { "username": "testing",
           "password": 'newpassword',
           "age": 22, "height": 179 
    };
    await User.remove({});
})

afterEach(async () => await User.remove({}));

it('signs up', async () => {
    await request(inst)
        .post('/api/v1/signup')
        .send(a_user)
        .expect(200);
});
```

The full **stack trace** of my error is:

```
  1) Authentication signs up:
 Error: expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"
  at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:266:12)
  at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:281:11)
  at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:171:18)
  at assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
  at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:128:5
  at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:631:3)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:795:18)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Only in tests but using postman works fine. Is there something i'm not doing right?

I'm using `koa: 2.0.0`, `supertest: 2.0.1` and for routes `koa-rest-router: 1.0.0`.

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad, I didn't perform it in "The async/awaits way".

**This**

```js
userInst.save(async(err, user) => {
        
        if(err) { return next(err); }

        const token = tokenForUser(user);

        ctx.body = token;

        return next();
    });
```

Had to be

**This**

```js
const user = await userInst.save();
const token = tokenForUser(user);

ctx.body = token;

return next()
```

I didn't put an await before `userInst.save`, causing the function to return an instantly resolving promise.